# Письмо не приходит на почтовый ящик

Tags: php, email

На хостинге заказал услугу электронной почты. Создал ящик support@mydomain.tk. Но после выполнения команды:

```
mail('mylogin@mail.ru', 'subject', 'message', 'From: support@mydomain.tk\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion());
```

письмо на другой почтовый ящик с ящика support@mydomain.tk не приходит. Как исправить

Comment: Обращайтесь в справку и техподдержку вашего хостинга за правильной настройкой почты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил вышеуказанную команду на:

```
mail("mylogin@mail.ru", "subject", "message", "From: support@mydomain.tk", "-f support@mydomain.tk");
```

и с почтового ящика support@mydomain.tk стали исправно приходить письма.